# Масштабирование TabControl`ов C# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-grid

Есть tabcontrol с tabitems. Реализовал масштабирование внутри tabcontrol но не знаю как масштабировать сами кнопки tabcontrol то есть TabItem`ы

Масштабировать главные grid при помощи  `<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>` и    `<Grid.RowDefinitions>` не могу так как сбивает все в других grid`ах

```
<Grid>
    <TabControl x:Name="MainTab"  Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Margin="0,50,0,-0.4" >
        <TabItem  Header="Anastasia" Style="{DynamicResource TabButtons}" >
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="279*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="185*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="230*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="46*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="46*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="46*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="46*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="46*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="46*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="62*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="33*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Viewbox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="7" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,2.8,0.2,0" Width="145"  >
                    <Button  x:Name="SendButt" Content="{DynamicResource SendMessageButton}" FontSize="10"  Style="{DynamicResource MainButtons}" Click="SendButt_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="55" />
                </Viewbox>
                <Viewbox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="7" Margin="0,2.8,0.2,0"  >
                    <TextBox x:Name="UserMessage" Height="25" Background="{x:Null}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Width="300" Foreground="White" KeyDown="UserMessage_KeyDown" PreviewKeyDown="UserMessage_PreviewKeyDown"   >
                        <TextBox.BorderBrush>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF00E2C3" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF5100C7" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </TextBox.BorderBrush>
                    </TextBox>
                </Viewbox>

                <Viewbox  Grid.Row="4" Grid.RowSpan="4" Margin="0,45.2,0.2,0">
                    <ListView x:Name="MainChat" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Background="{x:Null}" 
         IsEnabled="False" Foreground="White"  BorderBrush="{x:Null}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TS}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding TempSelect}" Style="{DynamicResource ListViewStyle}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="300" Height="100" >
                    </ListView>
                </Viewbox>
                <Viewbox Grid.Row="4"  HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Width="10" Margin="0,45.2,0.2,0.8" Grid.RowSpan="2" >
                    <Label x:Name="UserCommand"  Foreground="White" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Width="10"  />
                </Viewbox>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem x:Name="MusTabItem" Header="{DynamicResource TabMusic}" Style="{DynamicResource TabButtons}">
            <TabControl  Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" >
                <TabItem Header="{DynamicResource Player}" Style="{DynamicResource TabButtons}" >
                    <Grid x:Name="PlayerGrid" Visibility="Visible">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="33*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="32*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="86*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="77*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="58*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="58*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Viewbox Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="0,0.2,114.2,0.2"  >
                            <ListView x:Name="PlayList" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Style="{DynamicResource PlayList}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource PlayListItems}"
                                      MouseDoubleClick="PlayList_MouseDoubleClick" Visibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Width="12" Height="16"  />
                        </Viewbox>

                        <Viewbox Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,1.2,0.4,1.8" Grid.Row="1"  >
                            <Label Content="{DynamicResource TabMusicPlayListLabel}"   Foreground="White" FontSize="15" Height="27"   />
                        </Viewbox>
                    </Grid>
                </TabItem>
            </TabControl>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: `<ColumnDefinition Width="279*" />` Кто вас учил такие коэф. ставить?

Comment: Никто, просто двигал и он сам выставился

Comment: @АнульевПавел: Вы бы не пользовались графической тулзой и перетаскиванием, а писали вручную. Вручную получается намного правильнее, точнее и эффективнее.